# Convert .NET object to BsonDocument using custom conventions

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to convert an object using custom conventions (basically disable `IgnoreIfNullConventions`) just for single call, without affecting global conventions registered in `ConventionRegistry`.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Have you tried? If so, what was the result?

Comment: Have I tried what ? I don't know how to do that, hence the question.